# Invalid argument value when import Oracle 10g .dmp file into Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle10g, oracle12c

When I try to import .dmp file which export from Oracle 10g R2 into Oracle 12c. Error happens as below

```
 impdp username/password directory=dmptemp logfile=dmplog.log dumpfile=Example.dmp
```

Error ORA-39001, ORA-39000 and ORA-39088 happens.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `=` sign:

```
directory dmptemp
```

should be:

```
directory=dmptemp
```